# Given positive matrix $H = A + i B \ge 0$, what constraints hold between real and imaginary parts $A$ and $B$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, symmetric-matrices, positive-definite

Let $H = A + i B \ge 0$ be a positive (semidefinite) $n\times n$ matrix with real parts $A = (H+\bar{H})/2 = A^\intercal$ and imaginary part $B = (H-\bar{H})/(2i) = B^\intercal$.  (Bars denote the element-wise complex conjugate.)  What constraints hold between $A$ and $B$?

**Alternatively phrased, what are necessary and sufficient conditions on real matrices $A$ and $B$ such that $A + i B \ge 0$?**

I expect this to take the form of an inequality roughly like "some part of A greater than some part of B", because given an $A$ and $B$ satisfying $A + i B \ge 0$ we have $A + A' + i B \ge 0$ for any $A'\ge 0$. That is, we can always make $A$ bigger.

It's clear $A$ is positive (hence symmetric) and $B$ is skew symmetric (hence not positive semidefinite unless $B=0$).  When $n=2$, $B = \left(\begin{array}{cc} 0 & -b\\ b & 0 \end{array}\right)$ has only one free parameter, $b^2 = \det B$, that must satisfy $b^2 \le \det A$.  (Indeed, for $n=2$, $A\ge 0$, and $B = -B^\intercal$, $A+iB \ge 0$ if and only if  $\det B \le \det A$.) What is the generalization of this condition to higher $n$? (We can tell the condition changes for larger $n$ by taking $A$ and $B$ to be block-diagonal and seeing that $\det B \le \det A$ does not imply a similar condition for the individual blocks.)

Comment: Your definitions of $A$ and $B$ have conjugate transposes when they should have complex conjugates.

Comment: Thank you. Fixed.

Comment: Take $z=x+iy$ and rewrite $z^*Hz$ in terms of $x,y,A,B$ and what it means that $z^*Hz\ge 0$ for all $z$.

Comment: I get that $x^\intercal A x + y^\intercal A y \ge 2 x^\intercal B y$ for all $x$ and $y$. Sort of informative, but not as clear as $\det B \le \det A$ for the $n=2$ case. Is there a further manipulation you suggest?

Comment: @JessRiedel You got one sign wrong. One possibility to write it is that the (symmetric) matrix $\begin{bmatrix}A & -B\\B & A\end{bmatrix}$ is positive semidefinite. It is unclear what kind of information you have in mind to get from. E.g. applying Schur complements or Sylvester criterion, one obtains lots of implication, including ones with determinants.

Comment: The block matrix condition mentioned in the comment above is also equivalent to the compound condition that $A\ge0$, $B=-B^T$, $(I-AA^+)B=0$ and $\lambda_\min(iA^+B)>-1$, where $A^+$ denotes the Moore-Penrose pseudo-inverse of $A$.

Comment: Thanks both.  A.Γ., do you mean an overall sign on the r.h.s?  Can't you get any sign you want by sending $y\to -y$, which is included in "for all $y$"?  @user1551 , in the case that interests me $A$ is positive definite, hence invertible, so the new condition would just be $\lambda_{\mathrm{min}}(i A^{-1} B)$, right?  That's quite helpful.

Comment: @JessRiedel Yes, and $\lambda_\min(iA^{-1}B)\ge-1$ is equivalent to $\rho(A^{-1}B)\le1$, where $\rho(\cdot)$ means spectral radius. (There was a typo in my previous comment: “$>-1$” should read “$\ge-1$”.) This is because all nonzero eigenvalues of $A^{-1}B$ must occur in conjugate pairs of purely imaginary numbers.